# linq to sql and inheritance question

Tags: linq-to-sql, single-table-inheritance

Does anyone know how to to get the inheritance code for a specific type (single table inheritance in Linq to sql) ?

When I create a new entity B (which is inherited from A), I would like to write some code in A, that is valid for all objects inherited from A.

However, when you create a new entity B, it's inheritance code is not yet filled in.
Is there any method to get the inheritance code based upon the type?
I know there is a metaTable property in the Table class, but it's private and the class is sealed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found it :

int inheritanceCode= (int)DataContext.Mapping.GetMetaType(instance.GetType()).InheritanceCode;